# How can I get MSBuild to copy all files marked as Content to a folder, preserving folder structure?

Tags: msbuild

As part of my solution build, I want to copy all "Content" files (asp?x etc) to another folder. Since these are so clearly tagged in the project, I thought there must be an easy way to copy these instead of writing my own post-build step with xcopy.
Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure this out - this msbuild thing is incompatible with my brain.
I just want a step like

but can't figure out the syntax to use.

Bat file syntax suggestions would not be an answer to this question - only pure msbuild solutions apply

Thanks,
Per

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily do this by the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DestFolder>..\Copy\</DestFolder>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CopyContentFiles">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(Content)"
        DestinationFiles="@(Content->'$(DestFolder)%(RelativeDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
</Target>
```

If you want to execute this as a post-build steps then you can just add AfterTargets="Build" for example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DestFolder>..\Copy\</DestFolder>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CopyContentFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(Content)"
        DestinationFiles="@(Content->'$(DestFolder)%(RelativeDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: How if at all can we do this without editing the original `csproj` file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577036/without-editing-the-csproj-file-get-msbuild-to-copy-all-files-marked-as-content

Comment: @ShaunLuttin see http://sedodream.com/2012/07/28/MSBuildHowToExecuteATargetAfterCoreCompilePart2.aspx

Comment: Not sure if MSBuild has got less verbose in the years since this was answered, but DestinationFiles="$(DestFolder)\%(RelativeDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" worked for me (ie skip the Content-> bit)

Comment: @piers7 that should work in this case since the task just get's passed @(Content) if it was passed other items it may not work correct w/o the Content-> bit

Answer (score 1):

I use the web deploy feature to package all content files up and then I can use web deploy to sync with a site or use xcopy or rather RoboCopy if web deploy is not an option.

The RoboCopy task is included in [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/).

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <PackageDir>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp</PackageDir>
    <ServerPath>\\server\path</ServerPath>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\...</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
</PropertyGroup>    

<ItemGroup>
    <Project Include="WebApplication.csproj"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Import Project="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />

<Target Name="Deploy">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(Project)" Targets="Build;Package" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)"/>
    <RoboCopy
        SourceFolder="@(PackageDir)"
        DestinationFolder="$(ServerPath)"
        Subdirectories="true"
        Mirror="true"
        />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Sayed didn't work for me because it also retained the original parent directory.  I instead used the following altered version and it worked beautifully and is a bit more elegant!

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DestFolder>..\Copy\</DestFolder>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CopyContentFiles">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(Content)"
        DestinationFiles="$(DestFolder)\%(RecursiveDir)"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: I don't think RecursiveDir works for *content* files in the project, only for file sets you've loaded from globbing against the file system.