# Without editing the csproj file, get MSBuild to copy all files marked as Content to a folder, preserving folder structure?

Tags: cmd, msbuild, csproj

## Question

Ultimately, we would like to use the command line to copy all files that a `csproj` has marked as `Content`, while preserving the directory structure, and without editing the original `csprog` file.

We have seen [How can I get MSBuild to copy all files marked as Content to a folder, preserving folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643615/how-can-i-get-msbuild-to-copy-all-files-marked-as-content-to-a-folder-preservin) This doesn't work for us, because it involves editing the `csproj` file. We want to avoid doing that.

## MSBuild?

We've thought of using `msbuild` via the command line but we don't know how to ask it to do *just* the equivalent of this:

```
<Target Name="CopyContentFiles">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(Content)"
        DestinationFiles="@(Content->'$(DestFolder)%(RelativeDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
</Target>
```

In other words, we would like to use the command line to *define* a target (not just specify one) from at the command line. E.g. in pseudo-code we want this:

```
msbuild MyApp.csproj /t:"Copy SourceFiles="@(Content)" DestinationFiles=..."
```

## XCopy?

We've also thought of using `xcopy` though we haven't determined how to ask it to only copy files that the `csproj` marks as `Content`.

Answer (score 1):

I use PowerShell.

If you have a script Get-VSProjectItems.ps1 like this:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $project
)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop';
$project = (resolve-path $project).Path;
$projectDir = Split-Path $project -Parent;
$ns = @{
    msb = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003';
}

Select-Xml -Path:$project -XPath:'//msb:Content' -Namespace:$ns |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty:Node | 
    % {
        New-Object psobject -Property:@{
            RelPath = $_.Include;
            Directory = (Split-Path -Parent $_.Include);
            FullName = Join-Path $projectDir $_.Include;
        }
    }
```

Then copying the content files becomes as simple as piping the output to a script block that creates the target folder structure and copies the file (nb: fragment below assumes you want to recreate the directory tree in current working directory):

```
.\Get-VSProjectItems.ps1 ..\SomeProject\SomeProject.csproj | % { 
    [void](mkdir $_.Directory -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue); 
    copy-item $_.fullname $_.relpath;
}
```